# Manage docker environment for Swarm running cluster with UPC

Tags: docker, docker-machine, etcd, docker-swarm

I have successfully running an UPC cluster with 3 ubuntu instances.

I want to access the docker swarm environment, either *docker-machine*, or *docker swarm manage*, but it has not been possible. The closest I've been has been adding machines via *docker-machine* with generic driver, but when I  try to add this using the *--swarm* parameter, this tells me that the machine does not belong to a Docker Swarm Cluster.

What I want to do is to execute commands within the Docker Swarm Cluster created with **UPC (Universal Control Panel)**.

Comment: i am having the same issue .. any updates on this .. were you able to resolve it ..

Comment: @naveen23 I found a solution and I post it, Please let me know if It works for You.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution right here, https://github.com/docker/ucp_lab at the end of this lab. You just need to follow a few steps:

1. Navigate to your UCP server in your web browser
2. In the upper right corner click admin and choose Profile
3. Click *Create a Client Bundle*.
4. Navigate to where the bundle was downloaded, and unzip the client
   bundle.

   `$ unzip bundle.zip`
5. Change into the directory that was created when the bundle was
   unzipped
6. Execute the *env.sh* script to set the appropriate environment variables for your UCP deployment

   `$ source env.sh`
7. Run

   `docker info`

   to examine the configuration of your Docker Swarm. Your output should show that you are managing the swarm vs. a single node.